# illogical use of past simple in this text

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

> Every now and then we have gone to the studio and recorded a free batch of songs, just to see what they **sounded** like on tape never thinking they'd one day end up on a double album.

What I don't understand is the use of past simple for **sounded** because both verbs before are present perfect which means that it is  still ongoing actions or  that it has  stopped very recently  and they are situated on the same time frame and suddenly past simple which means that the action  is over. It is illogical for me if they still go to the studio they still record and the songs still sound.

Comment: It's a subordinate clause.

Comment: ....and would you mind explaining why it is past simple

Comment: It's simply like *I know what they said about that*

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean

Comment: It's the present perfect which is illogical here, I guess (not a native speaker!). I'd say: Every now and then we **went** to the studio and recorded a free batch of songs, just to see what they sounded like on tape never thinking they'd one day end up on a double album.

Comment: @Rola Abu-Ghazaleh _The sudden line of white foam every now and then streaked the dark green waves. Every now and again a passenger would pass through the carriage on the way to the bathroom. Now and then she would come in to check on me._ What's wrong?